# Erro "Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response"

Tags: php, angularjs

Estou fazendo minha api, em php, e recebo o seguinte aviso

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://vigilantescomunitarios.com/serviapp/api_gustavo/register.php. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Segue o início do meu código php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("conexao.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

$eh_profissional = $data->is_professional;
```

Segue meu controller:

```
angular.module('servi.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.controller('cadastroCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', 
$cordovaSQLite', '$window', '$state', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, 
$cordovaSQLite, $window, $state) {

$scope.email = [];

$scope.cadastrar = function(usuario){

$http.post("http://vigilantescomunitarios.com/serviapp/api_gustavo/register.php", usuario).success(function(response){
        // http://vigilantescomunitarios.com/serviapp/api/register

        })
    }

}])
```

Alguém sabe qual o problema?
Obrigado.

Comment: Meu caso e diferente... Estou acessando uma url externa e não local.

Comment: Concordo com o Gustavo, o erro é outro... Gustavo a mensagem diz que ao tentar enviar uma requisição com o header `Content-Type` (talvez um ajax) ele não foi liberado no `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, estou procurando ver se tem um resposta sobre isto. PS: titulo revertido, acho que vc já tem experiencia o suficiente no site para entender a utilidade do titulo da pergunta para torna-la proveitosa a futuros visitantes.

Comment: @GustavoSevero e Guilherme, voto retirado.

Comment: @diegofm não é o mesmo erro, apesar de estar relacionado o problema é especificamente o comportamento do `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'valor customizado')` (ajax), os 3 valores aceitos são `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` e `text/plain`, mas libs JS como Angular e jQuery geralmente usam `application/json` o que não é padrão.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O erro fala que não foi permitido o uso/customização do header `Content-Type` na **requisição** (por exemplo quando o Ajax requisita teu PHP) e que deve liberar usando [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)

Pelo Ajax os únicos headers que você pode ajustar são:

- `Accept`
- `Accept-Language`
- `Content-Language`
- `Content-Type`, no entanto este ultimo permite apenas os valores:

  1. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
  2. `multipart/form-data`
  3. `text/plain`

  No seu caso o `$http.post` (Angular.js) deve estar enviando algo como `application/json`, o que não é um dos 3 valores citados permitidos.

Então no PHP pode ajustar para:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
```

Comment: Agora parece que deu certo.
Só estou tendo problemas com o PDO kkkkk

Comment: @GustavoSevero que bom então resolvido né? Sobre o PDO o problema já é outro, recomendo abrir um pergunta especifica ;)

Answer (score 0):

Caso você não tenha acesso ao servidor para adicionar os cabeçalhos:

Pode usar uma das extensões para o chrome **(para desenvolvimento)**:

[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

[CORS Toggle](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/omcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh)

Estas extensões desabilitam a segurança do chrome com relação a comunicação de hosts diferentes e sem a definição de autorização no cabeçalho (como feita pela função header() ).

**Resumindo** este erro é corrigido adicionando: **(PHP)**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
```

Ou
seu front-end que consome a API deve estar no mesmo host(IP + porta) da sua API.